# How to improve if condition for better results?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have to add a if condition in my script. In this condition, a script will run on the remote machine and if output of that script contain desire pattern/text then condition is true otherwise false.

The scrip is as below:

> `ssh autoengine@dell425srv "cd /net/dell425srv/dell425srv2/apps/;./check_status_splunkforwarder2.sh"`

Output After running the script:

> bash$ ssh autoengine@dell425srv "cd /net/dell425srv/dell425srv2/apps/
>   ; ./check_status_splunkforwarder2.sh" splunkd is running (PID: 537).
>   splunk helpers are running (PIDs: 538).

If condition is true it display "splunkd is running" otherwise "splunkd is not running".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return code of `grep` directly, like this :

```
# Remote command in function (for readability only)
remote_command()
{
ssh autoengine@dell425srv "cd /net/dell425srv/dell425srv2/apps/;./check_status_splunkforwarder2.sh"
}

if
  remote_command | grep -q "splunkd is running"
then
  echo "splunkd is running"
else
  echo "splunkd is not running"
fi
```

You could have code that differentiates between a failed remote command execution and a failed `grep` :

```
return_code=0
output=$(remote_command) || return_code=$?

if
  ((return_code))
then
  echo "Remote command failed"
elif
  grep -q "splunkd is running" <<<"$output"
then
  echo "splunkd is running"
else
  echo "splunkd is not running"
fi
```